# Symfony2 Doctrine combining three queries

Tags: symfony

I'm building a simple task planner. This is a fragment from the file TaskController.php. How can I combine these 3 queries (tasks, notcompleted, completed) to make it work? Should I use DQL?

```
 /**
 * Lists all task entities.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="task_index")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function indexAction()
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $tasks = $em->getRepository('TaskBundle:Task')->findByUser($this->getUser());      // all tasks of a specific user

    $notcompleted = $em->getRepository('TaskBundle:Task')->findByCompleted(false); //tasks that are not completed

    $completed = $em->getRepository('TaskBundle:Task')->findByCompleted(true); // all completed tasks


    return $this->render('task/index.html.twig', array(
        'notcompleted' => $notcompleted,
        'completed' => $completed,
        'tasks' => $tasks,
    ));


}
```

Comment: I want to show all completed tasks of the logged user and then not completed tasks of the logged user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Doctrine's `\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection::partition()` to split the tasks:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$tasks = $em->getRepository('TaskBundle:Task')->findByUser($this->getUser());

$collection = new ArrayCollection($tasks);

list($completed, $notcompleted) = $collection->partition(function ($key, Task $task) {
    return $task->isCompleted();
});

return $this->render('task/index.html.twig', array(
    'notcompleted' => $notcompleted,
    'completed' => $completed,
    'tasks' => $tasks,
));
```

Comment: Cool, it works! Just wondering, is there a way to do this using DQL?

Comment: @Blazej I don't think it;s possible directly but take a look here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#new-operator-syntax You can implement this logic in the DTO's constructor. Or a better idea would be to make a repository method to handle this logic. Also, please accept my answer if you are using it (general StackOverflow idea/rule)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution could be to filter tasks in the controller:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$tasks = $em->getRepository('TaskBundle:Task')->findByUser($this->getUser());

$notcompleted = $completed = [];

foreach ($tasks as $task) {
    if ($task->isCompleted()) {
       $completed[] = $tasK;
    } else {
        $notcompleted[] = $task;
    }
}

return $this->render('task/index.html.twig', array(
        'notcompleted' => $notcompleted,
        'completed' => $completed,
        'tasks' => $tasks,
    ));
```

In this solution you are doing only one DB query, instead of three queries.